# Running out of heap space with small files

Tags: java, memory-leaks, bluej

I have a game that uses an ArrayList to keep track of obstacles on the screen (which are flowing down from the top). Once they reach the bottom, they are removed. I have a main class and an Obstacle class. Obstacle contains a method that returns one of my image files as a BufferedImage. The image files are no more than 10K, some are less than 1K. I am aware that I can use -Xmx to increase maximum heap space, but I don't think that that is the issue, as the files are very small. My thought is that heap space is reserved for the image, but once it is no longer used, that space is still reserved. I googled a bit, and found that Java has a "Garbage Collector" that should be freeing the heap space back up once the image is no longer in use. In addition to using files that are too large, there is also something called a "memory leak." It is a very simple program, an I read that memory leaks happen slowly, but I get the `Java OutOfMemory Error: heap space` within a minute usually.
Inside the while loop of the main class:

```
JLabel freshObsLabel = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < obsList.size(); i++) //looping through list of obstacles
   {
       freshObsLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(obsList.get(i).getObsImg())); //error occurs on call to getObsImg()
       frame.getContentPane().add(freshObsLabel);
```

getObsImg() method in the Obstacle class:

```
String obsImgDirectory;
BufferedImage obstacleImg;
public BufferedImage getObsImg() //gets BufferedImage corresponding to keyword given in constructor
{
    obsImgDirectory = obstacleType + "Obs.jpg";
    try {
        obstacleImg = ImageIO.read(new File(obsImgDirectory)); //line on which the error occurs
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("'" + obsImgDirectory + "' could not be read or '" + obstacleType + "' is an invalid obstacle type.");
        e.getStackTrace();}
    return obstacleImg;
}
```

Thank you, and I hope this question is well received, as I may be blocked if it isn't. I am very new to java, so I would ask that you take it easy on me because of that.

Comment: I can see that you add your label+image to content pane. But do you remove them? Also, how big is that list of obstacles you iterate over?

Comment: There are a total of 3 images that I use, but there are many obstacles. The  list of obstacles starts as empty, but a new obstacle is added every 3 seconds. The obstacles move down the screen at 1 pixel every .75 seconds, and when they reach the bottom (1500 pixels away) they are removed from the list. There aren't many obstacles accumulating in the list, and none of them use very large files, so I don't think that all of the heap space would be used.

Answer (score 1):

> I googled a bit, and found that Java has a "Garbage Collector" that should be freeing the heap space back up once the image is no longer in use.

You need to do more than "google a bit". Garbage collection, or GC, is fundamental to Java and you had darn well better study it thoroughly. This is not an area where one can skim or be lazy.

What do you understand "no longer in use" to mean?

It means that there are no places where a reference to the object exists.

Problem #1 is that your `getObsImg` method directly manipulates an instance variable, `obstacleImg`, even going so far as to `return obstacleImg;`! The method should not reference an extrinsic variable that way, it should assign a local variable and return that.

It's OK to assign the returned value to the instance variable. But you must control the references to the created object, as clearly you aren't yet.

Once you have assigned the reference to the instance variable `obstacleImg`, the object cannot be collected ("GCed") until that variable is reassigned a different value or its owning `Obstacle` instance is "no longer in use". That means that any variable, array, or collection that points to the `Obstacle` will keep it alive, along with its image.

Likewise if you were so foolish as to assign the `obstacleImg` value to any other variable, or element of a container, then that other reference will keep the image alive until all such references are reassigned, go out of scope, or all references to their containing objects in turn do so.

So look for where you have kept the `Obstacle` alive, including through containers, and where else you might have kept the image alive. Don't cross over scopes by directly assigning to extrinsic variables. And for pity's sake, study scope and garbage collection.

Comment: I didn't intend to skim or be lazy, I was just unfamiliar with GC before now, since I haven't been working with Java for long, and did not realize its importance. I really am a beginner at Java, and didn't know that I needed to study scope and garbage collection "for pity's sake".

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use a temporary variable to return, and then set obstacleImg to null? Some of this is a bit advanced for me, and I don't think I understand fully.

Comment: Don't get upset, Nate. I said "one", not "you". This is engineering, not a cocktail party.

Comment: Let's drop the word "temporary". A method shouldn't return an extrinsic variable. It should use local variables. As you study scope it'll get clearer how the local reference goes away at the closing brace (of the method in this case). That's one less reference to confuse the GC analysis.